# I am getting error when opening a CSV file in pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I am using *pycharm* and when i run a code of opening a `csv` file using `pandas` I am getting an error of no existence.
I saved the `csv` file in my project directory and called it using `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("E:\\students")
print(df)
```

The error when i run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:/untitled232/file1.py", line 2, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv("E:\\students")   File "E:\untitled232\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)   File "E:\untitled232\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 440, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)   File "E:\untitled232\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 787, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)   File "E:\untitled232\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1014, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)   File "E:\untitled232\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1708, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)   File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 384, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__   File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 695, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source FileNotFoundError: File b'E:\\students' does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had to put `.csv` after the name.

Comment: Moral: When programming, switch off the Windows Explorer option to "hide known extensions", because you need to know exactly what the filename really is, more than you need a prettified version of it.